# Adding a button on clicking a radio button having same value as of the radio button

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to Javascript and HTML.
I am working on a project which have a lot of radio buttons.

```
<input type="radio" name="name" value="Run $temp" data-href="test.pl" onclick="function()"/>Text
```

I want to display a button with the value same as of the radio button(which is "Run $temp" in this case) after this "Text", whenever I click on the radio button.
How should I write function().
Thanks

UPDATED

```
<input type="radio" name="name" id="button1" value="Run $temp" data-href="test.pl" onclick="doStuff('id')"/>Text
```

JS

```
<script>
var prevButton;

function doStuff(id) {
if(prevButton){
  prevButton.parentNode.removeChild(prevButton);
}
var radio= document.getElementById(id);
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerHTML = radio.value;
radio.parentNode.insertBefore(button,  radio.nextSibling.nextSibling);


prevButton = button;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try doing this on click.

**UPDATED**

You have to keep reference of previous button added, to remove it when the next radio button is clicked.

Pass the name of the radio button you want to bind this function with.

```
<input type="radio" id="thisId" value="Run $temp" data-href="test.pl" onclick="doStuff('thisId');"/>Text    

<script>
var prevButton;

function doStuff(id) {
  if(prevButton){
      prevButton.parentNode.removeChild(prevButton);
  }
  var radio= document.getElementById(id);
  var button = document.createElement('BUTTON');
  button.innerHTML = radio.value;
  radio.parentNode.insertBefore(button,  radio.nextSibling.nextSibling);


    prevButton = button;
}
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

document.getElementById(id) returns one element and not an array, so there's no need for [0] to select the first element. Either that's the mistake you were making Or, its that you typed ID in all caps, document.getElementBy**Id**(id). Id has smaller **d**.

here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TWb29/4/).

Comment: Thanks this worked .. but its giving a new button whenever I am clicking the same radio button. I want to hide previous button and create a new one when clicked on a radio button. How to do that?

Comment: Thanks .. I am trying to do this task by "id" element of radio button by using document.getElementByID(id) its not working .. I inserted a ID in radio button but its not working .. see UPDATED question

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. last query, how to align this button to right?

Comment: But that will align all my buttons to right as I have other buttons in the project.

Comment: Do it through javascript in the same method, like this. button.style.float = "right";

Comment: Thanks css worked but not the javascript. But its ok...working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you want to do, but try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setText() {
        var textValue = document.getElementById("new_value");
        textValue.innerHTML = "Text";
    }
</script>
<input type="radio" name="name" value="Run $temp" data-href="test.pl" onclick="setText()"/><span id="new_value"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Will [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/p9HFeQu7jOI6fCOTSYrC?p=preview) get you started?

```
function createBtn() {
    var radioBtn = document.getElementById("run-temp-btn"),
        radioBtnText = radioBtn.value,
        btn = document.createElement("button"),
        t = document.createTextNode(radioBtnText),
        row1 = document.getElementById("row-1");

    btn.appendChild(t);
    row1.appendChild(btn);
}
```

Comment: It's basically just a wrapper div for: the radio button, the label and the button that will be added dynamically on click.